# Efficient algorithm to find the outflow of a lake

Tags: optimization

Consider a raster image representing a elevation map

$$
z = f(x, y)
$$

An "extended lake" $L$ is the largest domain such that the elevation of every point $\partial L$ is greater than the elevation of any point within $L$. The outflow $P$ is the point on $\partial L$ with the lowest elevation. I came up with the following algorithm in order to find $P$:

1. Let $\partial L$ be the set of points on the boundary
2. Define visit($O$) as follows:

   1. Assume $O\in L$
   2. For all $P_k$ in $\{(x + 1, y),\, (x, y +1),\, (x - 1, y),\, (x, y - 1)\}$

      1. If $P_k$ is visited, continue
      2. If $P_k$ is outside the domain, continue
      3. If $f(P_k) < f(O)$

         1. add $O$ to $\partial L$
         2. continue
      4. visit $P_k$
3. Pick any point $P\in L$ and visit $P$
4. Return the element $P$ in $\partial L$ that minimizes $f(P)$

While this works, the algorithm may need to visit too many pixels. Is it possible to avoid the full search by using a clever strategy such (for example) as a greedy choice of $P_k$. That is, only consider $P_k: f(P_k) < f(P_l) \land f(P_k) \geq f(O)$. Terminate when $f(P_k) < f(O)$, with $P_k$ as the outflow.

Comment: What is the purpose of "save add $P_k$ to $\partial L$" ? Do you mean that $\partial L$ is not known ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular relation between the elevations of the points of $\partial L$, so you can't avoid an exhaustive traversal of $\partial L$. Make sure that the boundary is 4-connected, otherwise looking only at the four neighbors may fail.

To find an initial point on $\partial L$, just walk straight from $O$.

Comment: Traversing $\partial L$ is cheap, it is the exhaustive search of the interior that is expensive.

Comment: Straight walk is cheap. Why would you need an exhaustive search ?

Comment: To find $\partial L$ in the first place.

Comment: @user877329: you don't seem to understand my proposal.